# Input String was not in Correct Format on Web App using HTML and VB.NET

Tags: html, sql-server, vb.net

I inherited this code at my job and I am now having some issues. When I run this bit of code I keep getting errors on this line of code

```
p = CInt(v.Substring(1, c - 2))
```

I have 2 check boxes in a table The first one votes for a person and the second checkbox votes for the person whose name you type in to the text box beside the checkbox. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

It is also not liking when a capital "C" is included in the textbox.

```
Public Function CreateVotingDataTable(votes As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim c1 As New DataColumn("position", GetType(Integer))
        Dim c2 As New DataColumn("sequence", GetType(Integer))
        Dim c3 As New DataColumn("wivalue", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add(c1)
        dt.Columns.Add(c2)
        dt.Columns.Add(c3)


        Dim votearray = votes.Split("|")
        Dim p As Integer = 0
        Dim s As Integer = 0
        Dim writein As String = String.Empty

        If votes.Length <> 0 Then

            For Each v As String In votearray

                writein = String.Empty
                Dim w As Integer = InStr(v, "#")
                Dim c As Integer = InStr(v, "C")
                If c = 0 Then
                    c = InStr(v, "W")
                End If
                p = CInt(v.Substring(1, c - 2))
                If w > 0 Then
                    s = CInt(v.Substring(c, w - c - 1))
                    writein = v.Substring(w, Len(v) - w)
                Else
                    s = CInt(v.Substring(c, Len(v) - c))
                End If
                Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                r("position") = p
                r("sequence") = s
                r("wivalue") = writein

                dt.Rows.Add(r)

            Next

        End If

        Return dt


    End Function
```

The value that is typed into the textbox should be carried over to the next page by the datatable. Which works sometimes but when you go back to change the value to the other checkbox it gives me the input string is not in a correct format or argument out of range exception:

> length cannot be less than zero.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: When this error occurs, what is the value of `v`?  And `c`?  The error is telling you that the resulting substring is not an integer.  So what is it?  What do you expect it to be?  Why?

Comment: What happens if v doesn't have either C or W in it? There is no error check for that, so I assume c is 0 when that error occurs.

Comment: `Dim c As Integer = InStr(v, "C")` What happens if C is the first character in v. The c becomes 1. Then `p = CInt(v.Substring(1, c - 2))` So we are trying to return a Substring(1, -1) Clearly, the root of your error.

Comment: InStr is one based. Most everything in .net is zero base. Please correct this code to using `v.IndexOf("C")` which is zero based. It will return -1 if not found.